# How to get multiple value from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to split the String value

I want to get the id....

```
Table1

ID 

001
002
003
```

Query

```
SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE (id IN ('" & Eid & "'))

If Eid = 001 means It is displaying id 001
If Eid = 001, 002 means id is not displaying
```

How to make a query for getting multiple id.

Need Query Help

Comment: In syntax works with each value in separate quotes....think of it as a series of equals...  in ('001','002') will work.  in ('001,002') will not.  I believe a like statement can handle this, though performance might become an issue.  edited for awkward wording, trying again :)

Comment: This code looks very suspicious. Unless you are *absolutely sure* that `Eid` cannot contain unsafe values, use parameterized queries instead of building SQL from strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetIDasTable] (
    @ids varchar(MAX), 
    @separator varchar(20)
) RETURNS @retTable TABLE(ID bigint)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @firstComma bigint
    IF (@ids IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        WHILE @ids != ''
        BEGIN
            SET @firstComma = CHARINDEX(@separator, @ids)
            IF @firstComma = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @retTable 
                    VALUES (@ids)
                RETURN
            END
            INSERT INTO @retTable 
                VALUES (CONVERT(bigint, SUBSTRING(@ids, 1, @firstComma - 1)))
            SET @ids = SUBSTRING(@ids, @firstComma + 1, LEN(@ids))
        END
    END
    RETURN
END
GO

DECLARE @IdList varchar(MAX) = '1,3'
SELECT id FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[fnGetIDasTable] (@IdList,',') il ON Table1.id = il.ID
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the `'` quotes:

```
SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE (Personid IN (" & Eid & "))
```

Your version was generating

```
... WHERE (PersonID IN ('001,002'))
```

which means there's a **SINGLE** value inside the set brackets. Without the single quotes:

```
... WHERE (PersonID IN (001,002))
```

you have **TWO** values in the set brackets.

However, note that the leading 0's may cause problems. They could be interepreted as octal values, so `009` would be interpreted as "10 decimal". You may have to pre-process your values to turn them into

```
... WHERE (PersonID IN ('001', '002))
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like Marc B's answer but my solution is a bit easier.

```
SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE id IN (
                                   replace(
                                           replace('" & Eid & "',' ','')
                                           ,',',''','''
                                          )
                                  )
```

First replace is removing space (if you have no space, you can remove this replace)

Second replace is replacing , to ','

Comment: The IN predicate expects a list of values, but these nested REPLACEs would return a string that contains a list but itself is a single value. The only difference from the OP's case would be that the string would contain single quotes around commas. The nature of passing the `Eid` value is such that these replacements should be done in the client code, not in SQL.

Comment: did you just mean ('1','2','3') will not be considered as list in mssql? I know that this will be considered as a list, not single string, in mysql (and maybe in Oracle also).

Comment: "should be done in client code, not in SQL" It is depended on situation.

Comment: The thing is, REPLACE processes a string and returns another string. It does not *split* the string into a set of multiple strings, even if you insert `'`s into it. For instance, the innermost REPLACE would obtain a string containing something like `A, B, C` or `A,B,C`. In that case the outermost one would produce `A','B','C`. Note that I am deliberately showing you only the contents, without the surrounding quotation marks, so you could see that you are not obtaining a *set* of strings, but just one string, as previously, only slightly modified by the REPLACEs.

Comment: Re: ‘It is depended on situation’ – You are right. But I am talking specifically about how `Eid` is being passed in this situation. Its contents is simply concatenated with the rest of the script, so the resulting one (the OP's version) looks like this: `… IN ('…some comma-separated list here…') …`. You have suggested adding quotation marks around commas. I understand your idea, but you are mistaken in assuming that adding them in SQL, using a bunch of REPLACEs, would result in multiple strings instead of just one. …

Comment: … But if the same were done in client and the result were concatenated with the script in the same manner as `Eid`, that would produce the desired effect (assuming that the surrounding quotation marks are left in place).

Comment: The correct notation of the resulting string that your REPLACEs produce is `'1'',''2'',''3'`. Note the repeating of `'`s. They must be repeated because they are inside a string. Of course, they are not duplicated actually, it's just the notation. If you do not replicate them, the result will be confusing: `'1','2','3'` – that indeed looks like several strings instead of just one that merely happens to contain `'`s in it.